# Dropdown menu on mobile not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a toggle dropdown menu button that appears on smaller resolutions/devices, but for some reason it isnt working. When clicked, nothing appears/shows.

Most likely there is something missing (JS function that makes it open maybe). Copying entire code doesn't make too much sense to me, so I am just using some of it:

http://goo.gl/TNixQe

Comment: Not an answer, but you are getting some JS errors - you might want to deal with them before moving on.

Comment: @tokmark, I have one question about jQuery mobile :) Should I ask here or can you contact me? I have e-mail in my profile. I wanted to message you, but you have no contacts.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

True about responsive design. Now I noticed it (but did you say about it in your question? nope.).

When I tried to resize window firebug had found this error:

[image]

This error appears in `js_func.js` file in 9 row. Are you sure you link libraries correctly? JS can't find `uniform()` function.

Possibly this error is appearing, because all your instructions are in simple `function`. Try to add them to `onload` handler. Possibly browser try to load this instructions before `uniform` library had been loaded.

I meant this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // use `uniform()` function on elements
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

It is simple drop-down menu, based on lists. It is working throw `hover` handlers.

You can't do 'hover' on your mobile device. You can tap on screen only.

If you want users with gadgets use your site, you have to create menu espesially for gadgets.

Small trick, which helped me (because I am lazy :)) is to assign `javascript:void(0);` to 1 level buttons hrefs. This worked on SGS2 and Xperia Z1, but I am not sure it will work everywhere. With that trick, a man will tap on menu button and drop-down menu will appear.

Comment: The website is responsive, there is a tap to open menu on the responsive layout when you shrink the websites width to a mobile view.

Comment: You didn't say about it in your question, so I didn't notice it. I updated my answer. Possibly this error is appearing, because all your instructions are in simple `function`. Try to add them to `onload` handler. Possibly browser try to load this instructions before `uniform` library had been loaded.

Comment: I am not the OP, but the title did say "on mobile", nice work on the new answer - and even though the old answer is not applicable, it is a neat trick.

Comment: @logikal Title says on mobile, but there are nothing about responsive design, thats why I started to talk about there are no `hover` action etc. After he said about responsive design, I tried to research the problem. Trick for what? 2 likes? 20 rep?

Comment: Nono, the lazy trick for getting around hover for drop down menus on touch screen devices.

Comment: @logikal oops. Is it normal practise? I found it accidentally. One of links was with such href and I accidentally tapped on it and found this trick.

Answer (score 2):

You have a javascript error on line 9 of js_func.js:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'uniform'`

This will be causing any code below it not to be run.

Could it be a missing plugin on the mobile version?

A quick google suggests that the issue is with your jquery verison, they say to downgrade to 1.8.3.

In your case you are using 1.8.2, so try upgrade to 1.8.3.